# How does sulfur has atomicity 8

Tags: atoms

How does sulfur has atomicity 8, when its valence electrons are 6 like oxygen- ie even 2 sulfur atoms can share a pair of electrons and achieve the octet rule, why should it involve 8 atoms?

Comment: You may want to clarify the question you're asking. Sulfur exists in multiple allotropes.

Answer (score 6):

[Octasulfur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octasulfur) is just one of few different [allotropic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_sulfur) of sulfur. It happens to be the most stable form at room temperature, but different conditions favor different forms. Thus, for instance, sulfur vapor usually contains $\ce{S, S2, S4, S6, S8}$, and the higher the temperature, the lower is the amount of $\ce{S8}$ molecules since they break up into smaller allotropes of sulfur.

So, while two sulfur atoms can share a pair of electrons by forming a diatomic [disulfur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfur) molecule with a double bond, so can also eight atoms, but by forming a puckered ring structure with few single bonds. Then it is basically the question of thermodynamic and kinetic stability, which form would dominate others at some particular conditions.